# Did "Cleaver" make money?

Tags: the-sopranos

Pretty simple question, did the movie ["Cleaver"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cleaver_(The_Sopranos)) from *The Sopranos* make any money for those involved with it?

In or out of universe answers accepted.

Comment: Make money how? What do you consider making money for those involved?

Comment: @Joachim, How about it sold well in theaters or they sold a lot of DVD's == revenue generated from from the movie exceeded the expenses, costs involved in making the movie. That is pretty straight forward economics, I am not sure how else you can interpret the question???

Comment: My point was that it is very vague and broad, especially because you don't differentiate between in- and out-of-universe. I'm sure everyone involved was paid, but that's not what you want to know, right?